Prove that $2\cos^2{\alpha}+3\cos^2{\beta}−2\cos^2{(\alpha + \beta)} \le \frac{10}{3}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

Prove that $2\cos^2{\alpha}+3\cos^2{\beta}−2\cos^2{(\alpha + \beta)} \le \frac{10}{3}$ where $\alpha, \beta \in (-\frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{\pi}{2})$.

My try :
$$2\cos^2{\alpha} -2\cos^2{(\alpha + \beta)} + 3\cos^2{\beta} = 2\sin{(2\alpha + \beta)}\sin{\beta} + 3 - 3\sin^2{\beta} \le \frac{10}{3} \implies 2\sin{(2\alpha + \beta)}\sin{\beta} - 3\sin^2{\beta} \le \frac{1}{3} \implies 3\sin{\beta} (2\sin{(2\alpha + \beta)} - 3\sin{\beta}) \le 1$$
can't proceed further

If you put $\cos \alpha = x, \cos \beta = y$, the problem becomes to prove: $$2x^2+3y^2 - 2\left(x\sqrt{1-y^2} + \sqrt{1-x^2}y \right)^2 \leq \frac{10}{3}$$

@Kraken btw is it simpler than the original problem ?

Maybe, might give someone an algebraic idea. I am currently trying my best but this seems rather tough.

$$y=2(\cos^2\alpha-\cos^2(\alpha+\beta))+3\cos^2\beta=2\sin\beta\sin(2\alpha+\beta)+3-3\sin^2\beta$$
$$\iff3-y=3\sin^2\beta-2\sin\beta\sin(2\alpha+\beta)=\sin^2\beta(3-2\cos2\alpha)-\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta$$
$$\iff\cos2\alpha(2\sin^2\beta)+\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta=y-3\cos^2\beta$$
Now,
$$\cos2\alpha(2\sin^2\beta)+\sin2\alpha\sin2\beta\le\sqrt{(2\sin^2\beta)^2+\sin^22\beta}=|2\sin\beta|$$
$$\implies y-3\cos^2\beta\le|2\sin\beta|\implies y\le3-3|\sin\beta|^2+|2\sin\beta|=3-3\left(|\sin\beta|-\dfrac13\right)^2+\dfrac39\le3+\dfrac13$$

Given expression equals
$\cos 2 \alpha-\cos \left(2\alpha+2 \beta\right)+\dfrac{3}{2} \left(1+\cos 2 \beta \right) = \dfrac{3}{2}+\cos 2 \alpha + \left(\dfrac{3}{2}-\cos 2 \alpha\right)\cos 2 \beta + \sin 2 \alpha \sin 2 \beta$
which by Cauchy- Schwarz
$\le \dfrac{3}{2}+\cos 2 \alpha +\sqrt{\left(\dfrac{3}{2} - \cos 2 \alpha\right)^2+\sin^2 2 \alpha} =\dfrac{3}{2}+\cos 2 \alpha + \sqrt{\dfrac{13}{4}- 3 \cos 2 \alpha} $
The expression $\cos 2 \alpha + \sqrt{\dfrac{13}{4}- 3 \cos 2 \alpha} $ can be shown to attain its maximum at $\cos 2 \alpha = \dfrac{1}{3}$
and hence the maximum value of given expression is $\dfrac{10}{3}$
